# How to view the content of a garbage collection?

Tags: c#, mono, garbage-collection, unity-game-engine

Is there any way to view the content of what is being garbaged?

Basically I'd to be able to see, when I have a GC spike, ok 1200 objects of such and such type have been collected, so maybe I can identify & refactor to avoid garbaging in the first place.

This is with Unity (Mono environment), so I can't use any heavy-duty tool like Ants Memory Profiler, or even Mono HeapShot because I don't control how the executable is launched.

I've read about GC notifications, but they don't seem to be included in the version of Mono Unity is using, and anyway I don't think it would give my the level of detail I want (would it?).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, no, you cannot fetch what is currently being collected. On top, even if you could, it would already being too late, as the GC only works on objects that have disposed of. After all, the GC work on object that are not referenced anymore.

You shouldn't have a "GC Spike" as the GC is normally intelligent enough to not bottleneck everything on a collection. On top, the GC rarely collect "right away" unless told to.

If for some reason you could prove that the GC is really a performance problem, you could create a kind of pre-collector where you would store items you are sure you want gone and it would release their reference at a slower rate and would call the GC on them manually.

Comment: It's worth noting that Unity has its [own way of destroying objects](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/7853/garbage-collection.html) (see duck's answer).  Additionally the Object.Destroy documentation notes that objects are destroyed after the current Update loop.

Comment: @Jerdak I'm not sure, but I think that only applies for Unity's Object. Might be wrong, but I think nothing forces you to derive from Unity's Object, which mean they don't follow the same destruction pattern.

Comment: That was sort of the gist of my comment.  I was making an assumption that the OP was trying to delete Unity gameobjects which derive from Unity Object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even if it's a no ;) !
Maybe I shouldn't have mentioned Unity, because what I want to achieve has nothing to do with the engine's objects, but with the managed objects. Suppose I have some ill-coded, heavy processes, that allocate stuff in loops every frame: I could pinpoint the issues if the GC told me "I keep garbaging 100s of List<>", etc.
So implementing my own pre-collector is not the idea, I want diagnostics. And yes, GC spikes are plentiful in Unity! GC is critical to performance, and the best solution IMO is to not garbage in the first place.

Comment: @benblo: In this case, the problem is still not the GC, but your code design. If you create and dispose lists every frame, you should consider creating them once and reusing and never disposing them. The List<> class has a Clear() method to reuse them. On top, if you know the number of elements that should exist in a list, you should not use a list, but a standard table. Video games rarely allocate large arrays on the fly while the game is running, because moving the memory around, allocation or deallocation is a relatively costly process.

Comment: Yes the problem is with the design! precisely! Basically I've inherited from a large codebase that I know for a fact is generating garbage. I'm looking for tools or solutions to help me pinpoint where it comes from.